# LiberOffice Calc apply style with only specifc attributes

Tags: libreoffice, conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc, styles

Consider this simple time tracking spreadsheet:

[image: conditional formatting]

I figured out how to use conditional format to apply a selected style to a region, in this case I use "Accent" for Fridays and Saturdays, and this while working have some undesirable side-effect.

Notice that "Accent" is not merely setting the font bold, but also makes it black. This also overrides the green color of the "In" and "Out" columns.

When I try to edit the "Accent" style

[image: Modify Style Accent]

I see that it has the "Black" attribute.

I am able to add attributes, but I was not able to remove an attribute to the style, to prevent it from being changed by the conditional formatting.

So my question is: **How to remove an attribute from a style?**

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

Apparently this is what the "Standard" button do:

[image: standard button]